# Android Client not able to connect to server in libgdx game

Tags: android

I need to connect to a server I've set up on my Mac, but the Android socket always fails to connect. If I run the libgdx game on my Mac and use "localhost" as the desired server to connect to, it works fine. I've included the relevant permissions in my Manifest file. I'm using the public ip address I found by just doing a google search for my ip. I've made sure the ports are consistent as well.

```
public class ClientServer implements AsyncTask<String> {

private int port;
private String serverAddress;
private DataOutputStream outStream;
//private DataInputStream inStream;
private MandelSample ms;

public ClientServer (String serverAddress, int port, MandelSample ms) {
    this.serverAddress = serverAddress;
    this.port = port;
    this.ms = ms;
}

public String fetchData (MandelSample ms) {
    SocketHints hints = new SocketHints();
    Socket clientSocket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(Protocol.TCP, serverAddress, port, hints);
    outStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    String messageIN="Default Message";

    try {
        outStream.write("This message is from Android".getBytes());
        messageIN = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())).readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Gdx.app.log("ClientServer", "An error occured", e);
    }

    return messageIN;
}

@Override
public String call() throws Exception {
    String s = fetchData(ms);
    return s;
}
}
```

My logcat:

```
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error making a socket       connection to 146.7.4.78:8080
02-24 09:51:59.872 16349-26646/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at    com.badlogic.gdx.net.NetJavaSocketImpl.<init>(NetJavaSocketImpl.java:51)
02-24 09:51:59.872 16349-26646/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidNet.newClientSocket(AndroidNet.java:70)
02-24 09:51:59.872 16349-26646/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.ClientServer$override.fetchData(ClientServer.java:35)
02-24 09:51:59.872 16349-26646/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.ClientServer$override.access$dispatch(ClientServer.java)
02-24 09:51:59.873 16349-26646/com.mygdx.game W/System.err:     at com.mygdx.game.ClientServer.fetchData(ClientServer.java:0)
```

Comment: Are you Sure that this is the IP of your machine in your local network? How can you Google your IP?

Comment: I guess there's a difference between a public ip address and my actual ipv4 one. This fixed it!

Comment: For Sure. The public might  bei (depending on your Operator) the IP of your router.